# .NetStandard 2.0, MongoDB Driver: FileNotFoundException for MongoDB.Bson

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have created a new project with .Net Standard 2.0 with the following dependencies:

- MongoDb.Driver
- MongoDb.Driver.Core
- MongoDb.Bson

However, when I run my program, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Coult not load file or assembly "MongoDB.Bson, Version=2.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am from the Java world and this has me stumped for the entire day today. I have tried adding all dependencies specified [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver) including the dependencies of the driver itself without any luck.

- System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter (>= 4.1.0)
- System.Linq.Queryable (>= 4.0.1)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have any luck? Experiencing the same issue here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I created a library targeting .NET Standard 2.0 which used the mongocsharpdriver package, and another .NET framework 4.6.1 project which in turn used the library (Console application).

The built went alright, however a FileNotFoundException arised on runtime.

Both this thread https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/410 and this article shed some light on the issue https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx

Basically the solution was to add a line to the csproj corresponding to the Console application:

> I can open up the .csproj file for the Framework projects and add this
>   line within the first  like this to change the restore
>   style:
>
> `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>`

After building again, the MongoDB.*.dll files were copied to the output folder.

Hope this helps and saves somebody elses time!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by right clicking on the project and changing the Target framework to 4.6.1 from from 4.6 and it worked.

Comment: changing from 4.5 to 4.6 or 4.6.1 did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after I added these dependencies my problem was fixed.

- MongoDB.Bson.dll
- MongoDB.Driver.dll
- MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll